# Excluding value from array & Counting it

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, sorting

How do I exclude and count values which are bigger than 4095 from this array:
EDIT: so this is the final code I have, it basically works on some mousepoints, however there are some exceptions where the difference between depth and neighbouring values are too big (see green marked box on http://s7.directupload.net/images/131007/uitb86ho.jpg). In the screenshot there is a red box, which contains 441 Pixels, and the average value of those 441 Pixels is 1198 mm, where the depth on x;y 15;463 is only about 614 mm. Have no idea where the bigger average values come from, since it should have been excluded with the if-condition (d < 4095).

```
    protected void imageIR_MouseClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the x and y coordinates of the mouse pointer.
        System.Windows.Point mousePoint = e.GetPosition(imageIR);
        double xpos_IR = mousePoint.X;
        double ypos_IR = mousePoint.Y;
        int x = (int)xpos_IR;
        int y = (int)ypos_IR;
        lbCoord.Content = "x- & y- Koordinate [pixel]: " + x + " ; " + y;
        int d = (ushort)pixelData[x + y * this.depthFrame.Width];
        d = d >> 3;
        int xpos_Content = (int)((x - 320) * 0.03501 / 2 * d/10);
        int ypos_Content = (int)((240 - y) * 0.03501 / 2 * d/10);
        xpos.Content = "x- Koordinate [mm]: " + xpos_Content;
        ypos.Content = "y- Koordinate [mm]: " + ypos_Content;
        zpos.Content = "z- Koordinate [mm]: " + (d);

        // Calculate the average value of array element
        int sum = 0;
        int i;
        i = Convert.ToInt32(gr_ordnung.Text);
        i = int.Parse(gr_ordnung.Text);
        int m;
        int n;
        int d_mw = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for (m = x - i; m <= x + i; m++)
        {
            for (n = y - i; n <= y + i; n++)
            {
                int d_array = (ushort)pixelData[m + n * this.depthFrame.Width];
                d_array = d_array >> 3;

                // With condition that if one of those values is more than 4095:
                if (d_array <= 4095)
                {
                    sum += d_array;
                    count++;
                    d_mw = sum / count;
                }

                tiefen_mw.Content = "Tiefen-MW [mm]: " + d_mw;
            }
        }
    }
```

So, the 'if' condition means if I have **d_array** (in my case 100 Pixels) from m = x-i to m = x+i and n = y-i to n = y+i which is less than 4095 then just do the 'normal' calculation where the average is the sum of all values divided by the number of total elements.

Now the 'else' condition means: if I have **d_array** value which is more than 4095, then it should be declared as 0 and it doesn't count in the average. Did I write the Syntax correctly?

Comment: Not clear what you want exactly maybe `int d_array_useful = Math.Min(d_array, 4095);`  that gives the value of `d_array` or `4095` whatever lower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `LinQ` to do this quite easily:

```
using System.Linq;
...
int[] values = new int[10];
// Fill array
...
int[] usefulValues = values.Where(i => i <= 4095).ToArray();
int numberOfUselessValues = values.Length - usefulValues.Length;
```

UPDATE >>>

Try this instead:

```
int count_useful = 0; // <<< Important to initialise this here

for (m = x - i; m <= x + i; m++)
{
    for (n = y - i; n <= y + i; n++)
    {
        int d_array = (ushort)pixelData[m + n * this.depthFrame.Width];
        d_array = d_array >> 3;

        if (d_array <= 4095) 
        {
            sum += d_array;
            count_useful++;
        }
    }
}

d_mw = sum / count_useful; // <<< Perform these sums outside of the loop
tiefen_mw.Content = "Tiefen-MW [mm]: " + d_mw;
```

Comment: I'm sure they could spare the few milliseconds difference.

Comment: I don't think I can apply directly **int[]** to this code: **int d_array = (ushort)pixelData[m + n * this.depthFrame.Width];** There is a Problem with **ushort**

Comment: Then change the type of the array? When you asked how to exclude a value from an array, I really hope that you weren't talking about your `int d_array` variable, which is clearly an `int` and not an array. I couldn't see any actual arrays in your code except for `pixelData`, but just assumed that you knew what you were talking about.

Comment: Hi, **d_array** is 0-dimensional-array (which is then integer). Sorry I have no programming knowledeg before, but how to Change the type of Array?

Comment: No, it didn't work, in case that all values from d <= 4095 then Count_useful will just be the total number of the elements. So the Thing I should do must be in the 'else' condition (d > 4095). I have declared **else { d_array = 0; }** and outside the condition: **sum = sum + d_array;** and **d_mw = sum / count_useful;** Now I only have to find out how to find out **count_useful** for else condition which is the number of total elements minus the number of **d_array** I sorted out. Any idea how do I do that?

Comment: Your condition was that *if one of those Pixels has a value bigger than 4095, then it should be excluded*. So surely, if none of them are more than 4095, then none of them should be excluded and then of course, `count_useful` will be the same as the total number... what else were you expecting?

Comment: Yes it is, but the difference is somehow too big (http://s7.directupload.net/images/131007/uitb86ho.jpg). The depth at x = 15 Pixel & y = 463 Pixel is 614 mm. The average between x = [5..25] to y = [453..473] is however 1198 - 614 mm = 584 mm. It is a bit weird for me. If you see the depth Picture on the right, the same area translated from the IR Picture should have an average value similar to the depth, and the black area in the depth Picture should excluded (that's the Pixel containing value > 4095).

Comment: I meant if I have different depth values from the area selected - see red rectangle - containing d_1 d_2 d_3 d_4 d_5 d_6 ... d_n with some excluded values (d > 4095), where do the bigger d values come from?

Comment: Dude, I can only go by what you tell me the conditions are.

Comment: Well I think your code is correct. I will just consult my Tutor first. However I can't vote up anymore since there are too many People giving vote down to my post (that's the risk giving a vote down)

Answer (score 1):

Just check before you do anything:

```
int d_array = (ushort)pixelData[m + n * this.depthFrame.Width];
d_array = d_array >> 3;

if (d_array > 4095) continue; // <-- this
```

Without knowing more.. its hard to give you a nicer answer.

Comment: Unsure of the downvote? If this is insufficient I will remove it.. ? Maybe I missed something completely? :/

Comment: Your answer is not useful, thus the downvote. It should be a comment.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I didn't see that (I don't know how I couldn't). I thought that you copied OP's code and said `Without knowing more.. its hard to give you a nicer answer`. Can you make a dummy edit so I can remove the downvote.

Comment: Many thanks. (although I normally try and give better answers!).

Comment: So what i Need is from those 99 values from **d_array** (see my Post edit), I Need to know how many of those exceeding value of 4095.

Comment: I have also thought about that Option. I can do this easily: **if (d_array < 4095) { sum = sum + d_array; count_useful = (1 + (2 * i)) * (1 + (2 * i)); }** But how should I write in the else condition? How do I translate this into C# Syntax: If d_array > 4095 then d_array should be 0 and it shouldn't be counted.